# Error en Observable - The Movie DB - Angular Page ("Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties...")

Tags: angular, async, observable, pipe

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con la API de TMDB y angular.
Estoy intentando acceder a los datos de detalle de la página a través de mi componente "detail" y me da el siguiente error: *"Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.ts(2740)"*

**Aquí la función que aparece en mi servicio "dataService":**

```
getMoviesById(id:string): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get<Movie>(this.url+`/movie/${id}?api_key=${environment.api_key}&language=en-US`);
  }
```

**Aquí el código de "detail-component.ts"**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/Model/movie';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/Service/data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  movie$ !: Observable<Movie>;


  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movie$ = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => this.dataService.getMoviesById(params.id));
  }

}
```

**Por último, aquí el código de "detail-component.html"**

```
  <img src="{{ movie.image }}"
        alt="Movie Image Not Available"
        class="movie__thumbnail-poster"/>
        <h6 class = title>{{movie.title}}</h6>
          <p>Release : <span class="p-1"> {{ movie.release | date }}</span></p>
          <p>Language : <span class="p-1"> {{movie.original_language}}</span></p>
          <div class="rating-circle">Rating: {{movie.vote_average}}</div>
</div>
´´´

Muchas gracias de antemano!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

**En tu clase:**

```javascript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/Model/movie';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/Service/data.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  movie$: Observable<Movie>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movie$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => this.dataService.getMoviesById(params.id))
    )
  }

}
```

**Luego en tu plantilla:**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="movie$ | async as movie">
  <img 
    src="{{ movie.image }}"
    alt="Movie Image Not Available"
    class="movie__thumbnail-poster"
  />
  <h6 class = title>{{movie.title}}</h6>
  <p>Release : <span class="p-1"> {{ movie.release | date }}</span></p>
  <p>Language : <span class="p-1"> {{movie.original_language}}</span></p>
  <div class="rating-circle">Rating: {{movie.vote_average}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

**Una breve explicación de los cambios:**

En tu clase aplicas un `pipe` con un operador `switchMap()` ya que debes tomar los `params` del primer `Observable` que es `route.params` y pasarle el `id` a tu segundo `Observable` que es la llamada del servicio.
En tu plantilla usas primeramente un `*ngIf` para asegurarte que renderice los elementos una vez que el `movie$` emita el valor con `async`. Usas el alias `movie` para ese valor emitido, y lo empleas en el resto de la plantilla.

Espero que esto te funcione y de tener alguna duda o presentar algún problema con el código puedes preguntar.

**EDICIÓN (Esto es opcional):**

Si deseas chequear los datos, por ejemplo imprimiendo en la consola, puedes realizar estos cambios temporalmente.
En tu clase en el pipe del `Observable` luego de aplicado el operador `switchMap()` aplicar un operador `tap()` que simplemente te permite obtener el valor que emite el `Observable` en determinado momento sin interrumpir el flujo del mismo.

Primeramente importas el operador `tap`:

```javascript
import { switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Luego lo usas en el `pipe` de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movie$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => this.dataService.getMoviesById(params.id)),
      tap(movie => console.log(movie))
    )
  }
```

Por supuesto existen otras opciones para este caso en el que quieres revisar tu llamada `http` al API sin necesidad de modificar tu código, como es el caso de las `DevTools` del propio navegador que suelen traer una sección de `Network` donde puedes observar las llamadas `http` que realizas y sus respuestas.
Simplemente creí oportuno introducir el uso del operador `tap()` ya que es muy utilizado cuando trabajas con tipos `Observable` y puedes usarlo en situaciones como esta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cybering!! Funcionó perfecto!! :)

Comment: Lo que no consigo es bindear la imagen, no entiendo por qué si el resto de información fluye correctamente... ¿Alguna idea? Gracias!!

Comment: Debería funcionarte o bien la forma que estás empleando, o `[src]="movie.image"`. Voy a agregar a la respuesta una forma de chequear los datos obtenidos de la llamada para que puedas ver si llegan correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por el tip! Lo he aplicado y esto es lo que sale por consola:
"tap 
Object { adult: false, backdrop_path: "/ugS5FVfCI3RV0ZwZtBV3HAV75OX.jpg", belongs_to_collection: {…}, budget: 0, genres: (3) […],"
La propiedad que debería de bindear en el html es backdrop_path, pero aun así, sigue sin mostrarse la imagen. No lo consigo entender cuando el resto de info la paso sin problema...

Eso sí, la consola me lanza ahora el siguiente error: GEThttp://localhost:4200/pIkRyD18kl4FhoCNQuWxWu5cBLM.jpg

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias por tus aportes!

Comment: Haciendo un poco un empastre, resulta que he modificado el html de la siguiente manera según el error que he visto en la consola:

<img src="{{'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/'+movie.backdrop_path}}"  alt="no hay">

Ahora sí me muestra la imagen!!! Alguna forma de hacer esto más limpio?
Es mi primer proyecto en angular (se nota :P) Gracias!!!

Comment: Lo que sucede acá es que tu API te devuelve una ruta relativa de la imagen, en lugar de devolverte la URL completa. En este caso pudiste resolver el problema porque conoces la URL "base" de la imagen, pero este no siempre es el caso porque puedes usar imágenes de distintas fuentes. En mi opinión, esto es más algo que se deba resolver del lado del backend y que te devuelva la URL completa.

Comment: De todos modos, si debes resolverlo tú, y resulta que esta URL "base" es la misma para todas las imágenes puedes hacer una variable en tu clase (o incluirla en los archivos de environment, que es mejor práctica), y luego usarla en tu template en lugar del string que tienes escrito, ya sea con Interpolation `src="{{ a + b }}"`o con Binding `[src]="a + b"`.